# python to split a long string into different rows

Tags: python

`123|china|jack|342|usa|Nick|324345|spin|Amy`

I want the end result like this(I know I need a new line for every 3 element):

```
123,china,jack
342,usa,Nick
324345,spin,Amy
```

Thank you

Comment: I have tries using SQL to parse this thing, but the file is too large and I am not really a expert on python

Comment: `string.split('|')` will do if `string = '123|china|jack|342|usa|Nick|324345|spin|Amy'` . try printing new line after 3 element It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that:

```
x = '123|china|jack|342|usa|Nick|324345|spin|Amy'

l = x.split('|')
new_l = [l[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(l),3)]
```

This will give you:

```
>>> for i in new_l:
...     print ','.join(i)
...
123,china,jack
342,usa,Nick
324345,spin,Amy
```

> Update: to read the file

To read the file as string do the following:

```
with open('your_file.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    x=myfile.read().replace('\n', '|')
```

Comment: sorry bother you again coder, instead of hard code x='123|china|jack|342|usa|Nick|324345|spin|Amy', I have tried use x= open("love.txt"), I have also change the cwd but nothing seems work? python is not readying the file :(

Comment: Did you try:  x=open('path_to_your_file.txt','r')  - you have to specify what you want the file for (read/write/append etc...)

Comment: x=open('test.txt','r')
l = x.split('|')

then I got "_io.textiowrapper' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: yes cause you will have to read the file first and store its contents as a string. Try as the updated version of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It could be done with one `print` statement

```
>>> d = '123|china|jack|342|usa|Nick|324345|spin|Amy'
>>> l = d.split('|')
>>> print(*list(map(lambda v: ','.join(v),[l[x: x+3] for x in range(0, len(l), 3)])), sep='\n')
123,china,jack
342,usa,Nick
324345,spin,Amy
```

So now step by step

```
>>> d = '123|china|jack|342|usa|Nick|324345|spin|Amy'
>>> l = d.split('|')  # splitting input string into list of str objects that separated with '|'
>>> l
['123', 'china', 'jack', '342', 'usa', 'Nick', '324345', 'spin', 'Amy']
>>> [l[x: x+3] for x in range(0, len(l), 3)]  # combining elements by 3
[['123', 'china', 'jack'], ['342', 'usa', 'Nick'], ['324345', 'spin', 'Amy']]
>>> list(map(lambda v: ','.join(v),[l[x: x+3] for x in range(0, len(l), 3)]))  # merging every sublist to str with ',' as separator
['123,china,jack', '342,usa,Nick', '324345,spin,Amy']
>>> print(*list(map(lambda v: ','.join(v),[l[x: x+3] for x in range(0, len(l), 3)])), sep='\n')  # final print
123,china,jack
342,usa,Nick
324345,spin,Amy
```